# "=' operator overloading in List with an Associative array as one item using C++/CLI

Tags: arrays, list, c++-cli, operator-overloading, associative

Any of you please advise me on how to overload a list with an associative array in it,  using "=" operator. C++/CLI is the laungauge i am using.

I want ot achieve something like this.

```
`myList[0]["Key"] = "1";`
```

where myList is
`System::Collections::Generic::List<AssociativeArray<String^> ^> ^myList`

Can any of you please give me some clues for this.

Thanks in Advance,
Peter K John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use `List<Dictionary<String^, String^>^>^`?

That syntax is already supported.

If however, `Dictionary` doesn't meet your needs (e.g. you want a trie structure instead of hashtable), the indexer implementation would look something like this:

```
generic<typename T>
ref class AssociativeArray
{
    // implementation details
    // ...

public:
    property T default[String^]
    {
        T get(String^ key)
        {
            T result;
            if (!TryGetValue(key, result)) throw gcnew KeyNotFoundException(key);
            return result;
        }

        void set(String^ key, T val)
        {
            SetValue(key, val);
        }
    }
};
```